# Why is it we can add multiples and powers of $x$ to a power series expansion without affecting the result?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, power-series

The Maclaurin expansion of $\sin(x)$ can be used to find the power series representation of functions like:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3}{6} - x + \sin(x)$$

But on evaluation the $\frac{x^3}{6} - x$ seems to be left out entirely.

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3}{6} - x + \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}$$

Why are they left out? shouldn't these terms be added to every term of the sum?

There are power series expansions for $e^x,\ln{x},\sin{x}$, but I don't understand how one would represent terms like $x$ or $\frac{x^3}{6}$ as a series.

Comment: The Maclaurin series of $-x$ and $x^3/6$ are clearly just themselves. If you replace the $\sin$ with its power series then you can see that you do not have to add $x^3/6-x$ to each of the terms. You can simplify the final result though: $$f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}.$$ (Note that the sum starts at $n=2$.)

Comment: ... so what this means is that the coefficient of $x^1$ in the series for $f(x)$ is $-1 + 1 = 0$, the coefficient of $x^3$ is $1/6 - 1/6 = 0$, and the other coefficients are the same as for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Gary I see, the first two terms of the series are canceled by $-x$ and $x^3/6$, and now I know Maclaurin series of polynomials are just themselves. Thank you. And Robert  mentions they cancel out too. Thanks as well.